# look for value within two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, variables, search, methods

This should be a personal-management-program for n employees. Some methods provide specific functions. The method I am working on right got very complicated for me as it was working at the beginning of the method creation and now not.

Issue: the method doesn't serve the purpose and give the name/surname searched for. Even if the name exists, it says it doesn't.

the method:

```
public static void search(String[] n, String[] lN, String[] addres) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please give the name: ");
        String n = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please give the last name: ");
        String ln = sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < lN.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n.length; j++); {
                if (ln.equals(nN[i]) && n.equals(vN[i])) {
                    System.out.println("The employee " + nn + " " + vn + " is existing");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("We couldn't find this employee in our system");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

if you have a question don't hesitate to ask. Don't know? vote up maybe others have the answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is currently looking at the first employee, and if the first employee does not have the matching first and last name, the program prints out "not found" and gives up the search (using `break`).

What you can do is keep a variable that tells if you have found a matching employee. If after the loop no match has been found, *then* print out the warning message.

You also have a double for-loop when you only need a single for-loop.

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nN.length; i++) {
        if (nn.equals(nN[i]) && vn.equals(vN[i])) {
            System.out.println("Der/die Mitarbeier/Mitarbeiterin " + nn + " " + vn + " ist vorhanden");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Dieser Name existiert im System nicht");
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing this but didn't know if it is practical, thank you, it worked. Would it be possible here to also print out the index position of the employee?

Answer (score 1):

You're using i to index both arrays, instead of using j for vN and you have a semicolon after here `for (int j = ...);` which makes it so the block afterwards is always executed.

```
public static void suche(String[] vN, String[] nN, String[] adres) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Geben Sie den Vornamen des Mitarbeiters ein: ");
        String vn = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Geben Sie den Nachnamen des Mitarbeiters ein: ");
        String nn = sc.nextLine();
        boolean foundName = false;
        for (String nn2 : nN) {
            if (!nn.equals(nn2)) continue;
            for (String vn2 : vN) {
                if (vn.equals(vn2)) {
                    System.out.println("Der/die Mitarbeier/Mitarbeiterin " + nn + " " + vn + " ist vorhanden");
                    foundName = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!foundName) {
          System.out.println("Dieser Name existiert im System nicht");
        }
```

Also, you are iterating through the vN array regardless of whether nn was found in nN or not. I modified the code to search for vn in vN *only* if nn is found in nN.

Comment: Hey Man, thanks for you reply. I tried your method but the j in the braces doesn't get recognized by IntelliJ (marked in red) and it says create local variable, although it got created and initialized in the for loop. Know what the reason could be? 
Thanks

Comment: There's a semicolon after the for (int j = ...). Remove it and it should work.

Comment: Your code teaches me a lot about java but it just got more complicated than necessary.